# Subgroup Correspondence preserves index

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a group $G$, given a normal subgroup $A$, there exists a bijective correspondence between subgroups of $G/A$ and subgroups $H$ of $G$ which contain $A$.

Can anyone give a proof that this correspondence preserves index? That is, if $H'$ is the subgroup of $G/A$ which corresponds to $H$, can you prove that $[G/A:H']=[G:H]$?

I have read this statement a few times, but I have not managed to deduce a proof of my own. Thank you for any input.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $p:G\to G/A$ is the quotient map, show that $gH\leftrightarrow p(g)H'$ is a one-to-one correspondence between cosets of $H$ in $G$ and cosets of $H'$ in $G/A$.  (It may be useful to keep in mind that $H'=p(H)$ and $H=p^{-1}(H')$.)